# BindingHandler in Knockoutjs. build own ListView

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I want to build my own listView with selectedItem and Itemsource.

I have started a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/andersb79/53xRL/1/

Can you please help me in the right direction about how I should build this.
I havn't seen a bindingHanlder that do this.

What I want is something like this.

```
data-bind="myListView : { items : comments, selectedItem : selectedComment}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom binding you need to:

1. Create an element for each of the items in the list
2. Append that element to the parent
3. Add a click handler to each element that sets the selectedItem on the original view model

I've also highlighted the current selected item for clarity.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myListView = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),

            //get the list of items
            items = value.items(),
            //get a reference to the selected item observable
            selectedItem = value.selectedItem,
            //get a jQuery reference to the element
            $element = $(element),
            //get the currently selected item
            currentSelected = selectedItem();

        //clear the parent of any existing children
        $element.html("");

        for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
            (function() {
                //get the list of items
                var item = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(items[index]),

                    //create a child element with a click handler
                    $childElement = $("<li>")
                    .text(item.id() + " " + item.text())
                    .click(function() {
                        //remove selected class on all siblings
                        $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
                        //add selected class on this item
                        $(this).addClass("selected");
                        //set the observable 'selected item' property on the source view model
                        selectedItem(item);
                    });

                //add the selected class if this item is the current selected item
                if (item == currentSelected) {
                    $childElement.addClass("selected");
                }

                //add the child to the parent
                $element.append($childElement);
            })();
        }

    }
};
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/stevegreatrex/53xRL/5/)

Note: As I am using the `update` instead of the `init` method it will work when updating the list of comments

**Update**

If you want to use the contents of the original DIV as the template for each created item, you need two additional steps:

1. Grab the original content of the element when initialized and use that in place of the hard-coded content above
2. Apply bindings to the created element before adding it to the DOM

   ```
       ko.bindingHandlers.myListView = {
   init: function(element) {
       var $element = $(element),
           originalContent = $element.html();

       $element.data("original-content", originalContent);
       return { controlsDescendantBindings: true }
   },
   update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
       var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),

           //get the list of items
           items = value.items(),
           //get a reference to the selected item observable
           selectedItem = value.selectedItem,
           //get a jQuery reference to the element
           $element = $(element),
           //get the currently selected item
           currentSelected = selectedItem(),
           //get the current content of the element
           elementContent = $element.data("original-content");

       $element.html("");

       for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
           (function() {
               //get the list of items
               var item = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(items[index]),

                   //create a child element with a click handler
                   $childElement = $(elementContent)
                   .click(function() {
                       //remove selected class on all siblings
                       $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
                       //add selected class on this item
                       $(this).addClass("selected");
                       //set the observable 'selected item' property on the source view model
                       selectedItem(item);
                   });

               ko.applyBindings(item, $childElement[0]);

               //add the selected class if this item is the current selected item
               if (item == currentSelected) {
                   $childElement.addClass("selected");
               }

               //add the child to the parent
               $element.append($childElement);
           })();
       }

   }
   ```

   };

Note that we have to prevent the content of the div being processed by knockout by returning `{ controlsDescendantBindings: true }` from our `init` method.

Here is an [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/stevegreatrex/53xRL/9/)

Comment: Whoo thanks a lot. But what if I want to be abel to have code inside the div that is the comment, or a template.
<div data-bind="myListView: {items:comments,selectedItem : selectedComment}">
    On the page I want code here that is a Comment.
    so I can do data-bind="text:comment" here
</div>

Comment: Great help. Cant you hook up and use the foreach binding inside the bindinghandler to take advantage of the template binding also so if i would have it like this. myListView : {Items : Comment,template : 'myTemplate',selectedItem : selectedItem}

And not have a for loop and instead have a knockout foreach. Is it possible? Is it better ?

Comment: It is possible and arguably better as we are slightly re-writing the knockout functionality here

Comment: In your example how can i get $parent to be the viewModel inside the div so I can do a remove and update, now in the div the $parent is a comment also.

Comment: For this given solution, if I wanted to add a custom method after the items has rendered in the DOM how would I go about doing this?  Seems like it should be in the update part of the method, but what event should I subscribe to?  This is associated with this other [question:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331621/refresh-masonry-layout-after-knockoutjs-databound-template-is-inserted-into-a-co)

Comment: @BigDubb what are you trying to do after the items are rendered?  You can probably just invoke your custom method immediately in the `update` handler