# Refresh masonry layout after knockoutJS databound template is inserted into a container

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-masonry

I have a knockout template binding used to bind list of divs to an observable array:

```
<div class="menu-instance-entries js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "gutter": 20, "itemSelector": ".menu-entry" }' data-bind="template: { name: 'menu-entries-template', foreach: MenuEntries }"></div>
```

`MenuEntries` is an observable array that gets a new element "`push`ed" into it by a click handler bound to a view model's function.

The layout of the elements in the `.menu-instance-entries` container is controlled by the [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin and in order for the manual absolute positioning to take place, one need to call `$container.masonry( 'prepended', elements )` passing the elements collection.

I am in control at the point of where observable collections' `.push` occures, but I have no idea how to get a jQuery element from a newly created div by template to pass onto a jQuery call to masonry plugin.

What should I do to have the layout updated on knockout element adding via observable array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the afterAdd or beforeRemove functions of the template binding, I advice against it though because you get dependencies to the DOM from the ViewModel.

Better to create a custom binding that handles the interaction between masonry and KO

Comment: I like this suggestion, and the reasoning behind it.  However I'm falling a bit short on implementation.  I followed an example given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031719/bindinghandler-in-knockoutjs-build-own-listview), with some tweaks of course.    Where in the update method would I adjust layout to resize appropriately.