# With custom binding for Masonry how would I resize the container appropriately

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-masonry, bindinghandlers

Based on the suggestion give [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331621/refresh-masonry-layout-after-knockoutjs-databound-template-is-inserted-into-a-co), and the information given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031719/bindinghandler-in-knockoutjs-build-own-listview) on how to make a custom bindingHandler for a forEach, I decided to attempt to write my own custom binding for a forEach and Masonry.

Because the elements are added on the fly the redrawing and moving around of elements to fill the space doesn't occur.  So, this functionality needed to be moved after the elements have been rendered or called after each item has been added.

Here is my bindingHandler

```
ko.bindingHandlers.masonry = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var $element = $(element),
        originalContent = $element.html();
    $element.data("original-content", originalContent);
    //var msnry = new Masonry($element);
    return { controlsDescendantBindings: true }

},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),

    //get the list of items
    items = value.items(),

    //get a jQuery reference to the element
    $element = $(element),

    //get the current content of the element
    elementContent = $element.data("original-content");

    $element.html("");

    var container = $element[0];
    var msnry = new Masonry(container);

    for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
        (function () {
            //get the list of items
            var item = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(items[index]),
                $childElement = $(elementContent);

            ko.applyBindings(item, $childElement[0]);

            //add the child to the parent        
            $element.append($childElement);
            msnry.appended($childElement[0]);

        })();

        msnry.layout();
        msnry.bindResize();
    }
}

};
```

and the HTML implementing the handler.

```
<div id="criteriaContainer" data-bind="masonry: { items: SearchItems.Items }">
    <div class="searchCriterion control-group">
        <label class="control-label" data-bind="text: Description"></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: Value, select2: { minimumInputLength: 3, queryUri: SearchUri(), placeholder: Placeholder(), allowClear: true }" style="width: 450px">
        </div>
        <p data-bind="text: Value"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When this shows up on the page It stacks all if the elements rendered via the append method right on top of each other.

You can see in my bindingHandler I am calling bindResize as well as layout(), neither of which seem to be having any effect.

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like in the UI. 
[image: Masonry example with Knockout]

Answer (score 2):

The custom binder I made is based on someone else's custom binding for isotope:  https://github.com/aknuds1/knockout-isotope/blob/master/lib/knockout-isotope.js

NOTE: The author of the custom isotope binding is using a *modified* version of knockout. The binding below uses the *standard* knockout library (I am using v3.3.0).

The trick to getting the custom binding to work is to use the afterAdd callback to track the added elements so you can append them to the masonry object.

```
"use strict";

(function () {
    var $container, haveInitialized, newNodes = [], itemClass, masonryOptions;

    function afterAdd(node, index, item) {
        if (node.nodeType !== 1) {
            return; // This isn't an element node, nevermind
        }
        newNodes.push(node);
    }

    ko.bindingHandlers.masonry = {
        defaultItemClass: 'grid-item',
        // Wrap value accessor with options to the template binding,
        // which implements the foreach logic
        makeTemplateValueAccessor: function (valueAccessor) {
            return function () {
                var modelValue = valueAccessor(),
                    options,
                    unwrappedValue = ko.utils.peekObservable(modelValue);    // Unwrap without setting a dependency here

                options = {
                    afterAdd: afterAdd
                };

                // If unwrappedValue.data is the array, preserve all relevant
                // options and unwrap value so we get updates
                ko.utils.unwrapObservable(modelValue);
                ko.utils.extend(options, {
                    'foreach': unwrappedValue.data,
                    'as': unwrappedValue.as,
                    'includeDestroyed': unwrappedValue.includeDestroyed,
                    'templateEngine': ko.nativeTemplateEngine.instance
                });
                return options;
            };
        },
        'init': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            console.log({ msg: 'Initializing binding' });

            itemClass = ko.bindingHandlers.masonry.defaultItemClass;
            masonryOptions = {};
            haveInitialized = false;
            $container = $(element);

            var parameters = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if (parameters && typeof parameters == 'object' && !('length' in parameters)) {
                if (parameters.masonryOptions) {
                    var clientOptions;
                    if (typeof parameters.masonryOptions === 'function') {
                        clientOptions = parameters.masonryOptions();
                        if (typeof clientOptions !== 'object') {
                            throw new Error('masonryOptions callback must return object');
                        }
                    } else if (typeof parameters.masonryOptions !== 'object') {
                        throw new Error('masonryOptions must be an object or function');
                    } else {
                        clientOptions = parameters.masonryOptions;
                    }
                    ko.utils.extend(masonryOptions, clientOptions);
                }
                if (parameters.itemClass) {
                    itemClass = parameters.itemClass;
                }
            }

            // Initialize template engine, moving child template element to an
            // "anonymous template" associated with the element
            ko.bindingHandlers.template.init(
                element,
                ko.bindingHandlers.masonry.makeTemplateValueAccessor(valueAccessor)
            );

            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        },
        'update': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            ko.bindingHandlers.template.update(element,
                    ko.bindingHandlers.masonry.makeTemplateValueAccessor(valueAccessor),
                    allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);

            // Make this function depend on the view model, so it gets called for updates
            var data = ko.bindingHandlers.masonry.makeTemplateValueAccessor(
                        valueAccessor)().foreach;
            ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data);

            if (!haveInitialized) {
                masonryOptions.itemSelector = '.' + itemClass;
                console.log({msg: 'Binding update called for 1st time, initializing Masonry', options: masonryOptions});
                $container.masonry(masonryOptions);
            }
            else {
                console.log({ msg: 'Binding update called again, appending to Masonry', elements: newNodes });
                var newElements = $(newNodes);
                $container.masonry('appended', newElements);
                $container.masonry('layout');
                newNodes.splice(0, newNodes.length); // reset back to empty
            }

            // Update gets called upon initial rendering as well
            haveInitialized = true;
            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        }
    };
})();
```

Here is an example of the binding in use:

```
<div class="grid" data-bind="masonry: {data: blogEntries, masonryOptions: { itemClass: 'grid-item', columnWidth: 320, gutter: 10}}">
    <div class="grid-item">
        <div data-bind="css: {'idea-blog': isIdea }">
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: imageUrl }">
            <h2 data-bind="text: title"></h2>
            <p data-bind="text: description"></p>
            <div class="button-keep-reading">
                <a data-bind="attr: { src: articleUrl }"><span data-bind="text: linkText"></span> &gt;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Be aware that you'll want to ensure any images you are using in your masonry tiles are loaded before you bind the data because masonry has problems layout problems otherwise.